# Why is there extra schema information on DataMember properties of base class when using WCF?

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have some DataContracts defined, one is inherited from the other. These are not the exact classes but there are something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseModel 
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Id {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class MyModel : BaseModel 
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name {get;set;}
}
```

I am using WCF with the basicHTTPbinding to move data from server to client. When I use fiddler to look at the data being sent it is doing something a bit strange.

In the raw data being returned, when I examine the Name property I can see 'Name' followed by the data. For the Id property I see 'Id http://schema.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyService' followed by the data. I only every see the schema.datacontract.org part for the fields from the base class. Why do only the inherited fields get that schema part? Both classes are in the same namespace. I don't want it on ANY properties as its adding significant size to my response.  Is there anyway I can turn it off?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I changed each [DataContract] to include Namespace with the same value, e.g.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyCode.Service")]
```

and this has fixed my issue. Not sure why it needed to be specified since they were in the same namespace already but it does work.